# How to convert one column to row in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataset with 3 columns, which looks like this:

```
SNP_id Beta Se 
rs234   0.2 0.1
rs452   0.3 0.2
rs785   0.4 0.3
```

I would like to turn the column SNP_id into a row, so like this:

```
        Beta Se 
rs234   0.2 0.1
rs452   0.3 0.2
rs785   0.4 0.3
```

How can I do this?

I tried this:

```
row.names(df) <- df$SNP_id
```

Any other solution? This works at first sight, however I ran into an error later

Comment: What exactly is the error you ran into later? What you wrote looks fine. But keep in mind that if you are using any tidyverse stuff, those functions tend to ignore/drop row names.

Comment: It might be good to know why you want to do this - is there some issue you are running into caused by having the row names in a column?  I'd imagine it's more likely that sorting out that interaction will be more useful than doing this.

Comment: Welcome to SO, narm! For clarity: you converted `SNP_id` into names of rows, not *"into a row"*. The code you have above partially achieves your desired end-state, though to finish it you'll need to remove the `SNP_id` column with `df$SNP_id <- NULL`. If you have an error later, please show the error that generated the error _and the error text itself_, since we can't help with what we don't see and cannot reproduce. Please [edit] your question to add context. Thanks!